# What's a I18N-friendly way to show a date range?

Tags: java, internationalization, jodatime

I show date ranges as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("nl", "NL"));

    DateTime d1 = new DateTime();
    DateTime d2 = new DateTime().plusDays(30);

    final String s1 = d1.toString(DateTimeFormat.shortDate());
    final String s2 = d2.toString(DateTimeFormat.shortDate());

    System.out.println(s1 + "-" + s2); // shows  "4/05/12-3/06/12" for en_AU
    System.out.println(s1 + "-" + s2); // shows  "4-5-12-3-6-12" for nl_NL
}
```

For users in Holland, they see "4-5-12-3-6-12". This is confusing.

What's a way to show date ranges that takes the user's locale into account?

Comment: I have no idea if 4/5/12 is May 4th or April 5th.  How about 4 May 2012 - 3 Jun 2012?  The month abbreviation would be locale dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a localized application, such separation would be decided by the translators when they translate your resource bundles:

```
#foo.properties
#comment: a date range
dateRange={0,date}-{1,date}
```

Might become:

```
#foo_en.properties
dateRange={0,date} to {1,date}
```

This can then be handled using the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) type. Something of the form:

```
//untested code
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(formatString, locale);
//java.util.Date instances
Object[] range = {date1, date2};
String result = mf.format(range);
```

Even if you're not providing full translations, this approach might be applicable for certain localizations.

Comment: I think I really knew this was the correct answer but my lazy side was hoping that it wasn't. Well, the app is fully translatable with resource bundles, so this will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use an ellipsis (...) instead of a dash?

Answer (score 1):

At least use more space around the values:

```
"4-5-12 - 3-6-12"
```

4 digits for the year are, afaik, understandable in every locale:

```
"4-5-2012 - 3-6-2012"
```

a fixed number of digits might or might not be your taste:

```
"04-05-2012 - 03-06-2012"
```

I don't see much improvement from the 2nd to the 3rd form, but to the 2nd, there is. We all have more often contact with smaller than with bigger numbers, and there are so few smaller numbers. 11, 12 and 13 cross your way often, but if you see a 2011, 2012 and 2013, it is, since a few years, mostly in dates.

Comment: Also note that the international date format is year-month-date, to avoid confusion over the order of month & date.

Comment: @Sprachprofi: Is there something like an international date format? Where is it defined? From other scopes, there are many interntional measurements, called the metric system, where especially the US does not conform to - see Inch, Gallon, Pound, Feet, Yard, Miles, ... - and: "take the users locale into account" was part of the question.

Comment: ISO has some standards for showing date, in YYYY-MM-DD format, for example. But generally, my users would appreciate seeing dates in the formats they are accustomed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf;

// Create new SimpleDateFormat object that returns default pattern.
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
String dateFormat = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("Date by SimpleDateFormat class : " + dateFormat);
```

And the output is:

***Date by SimpleDateFormat class : 6/14/08 1:15 PM***